# Pourquoi est-ce que les privilèges sur FSE demandent (beaucoup) moins de réputation que sur d'autres sites de SE ?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Je viens de jeter un oeil aux privilèges atteignables sur Frensh Stack Exchange, et j'ai été surpris de voir qu'un utilisateur avec 5.000 points a déjà accès à la totalités d'entre eux:

[image: FSE privilèges]

Initialement, je viens de Physics Stack Exchange et de Math Stack Exchange. Sur ces sites-là, les privilèges demandent beaucoup plus de points de réputation. Par exemple, PSE demande 5 fois plus de points de réputation :

[image: PSE privilèges]

Ceci est d'autant plus étonnant que les *upvotes* sont beaucoup plus fréquents sur FSE et les *downvotes* beaucoup plus rares (je ne sais pas comment traduire ces mots correctement, je poserais d'ailleurs peut-être une question dessus). Je peux vous assurer que la différence est notable, et qu'il est de toute évidence beaucoup rapide de progresser en réputation sur FSE que PSE. Je me demandais donc s'il y avait une raison particulière pour ceci (peut-être la communauté de FSE est-elle beaucoup plus petite que celle de PSE ?).

Answer (score 1):

Oui, peut-être la communauté de FSE est plus petite que celle de [[Physics.SE]] dont ce dernier a posé plus de 200.000 questions et nous à peu près 13.000.  Donc on fait attention aux maths pour la modération qui donne des privilèges quant à la réputation et le nombre d'utilisateurs.

Il y a des sites SE assez petites ou spécialisées surtout en langues (linguistique et littératures ci-inclus) qui marchent comme ça. (N'oublions pas que 300 millions du monde parlent français et le français fait l'une des cinq langues plus employées.)

Il y a aussi des communautés plus  grandes qui emploient de différentes méthodes de modération (3 votes pour fermer par exemple).  Ce n'est pas étonnant et notre communauté se soutient bien.  Moi, je suis membre depuis presque dix ans mais ce n'est pas à cause de la gamification de réputation.

Pour ce qui est des votes plussoyés ou moinsoyés, je trouve très agréable d'accueillir de bonnes questions et de bonnes réponses de la communauté.  Je ne me plains pas de la taille de notre liste des questions spam ou LQ. En fait je dirais qu'on devrait continuer à voter, à plussoier beaucoup de bonnes questions pour encourager de bonnes questions surtout si on y répond.

Est-ce bien gentil d'avoir créer et abîmé ton nom d'utilisateur afin de poser cette question dont la réponse est très disponible ?